# Как добавить метод удаления с помощью NodeJS и axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Как добавить метод удаления? Я попытался добавить метод удаления, но получаю ошибку 400 - Bad Request. [Здесь](https://repl.it/@AlisaAli/FrostyDarkredGigabyte) есть все файлы проекта, вы можете добавить метод удаления в файле routs/oss.js. Заранее благодарен.

/routes/oss.js.

```
router.delete('/objects/:id', multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }).single('fileToDelete'), async (req, res, next) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  try {
    // Upload an object to bucket using [ObjectsApi](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#uploadObject).
    // await new ObjectsApi().deleteObject(id, {}, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
    await new ObjectsApi().deleteObject(req.body.bucketKey);
            res.status(200).end();
        } catch(err) {
            next(err);
        }
});


/public/js/ForgeTree.js

case "object":
  items = {
    translateFile: {
      label: "Translate",
      action: function () {
        var treeNode = $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).get_selected(true)[0];
        translateObject(treeNode);
      },
      icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'
    },
    deleteFile: {
      label: "Delete",
      action: function () {
        var treeId = $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).get_selected(true)[0].id; deleteBucket(treeId);
      },
      icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'
    }
  };
  break;
```

/public/js/ForgeTree.js

```
function deleteBucket(id) {
  id = $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).get_selected(true)[0].id;
  console.log('delete id ' + id);
  $.ajax({
      url: '/api/forge/oss/objects/' + encodeURIComponent(id),
      type: 'DELETE'
  }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.status === 'success') {
          $('#forgeFiles').jstree(true).refresh()
          showProgress("Bucket deleted", "success")
      }
  }).fail(function(err) {
      console.log('DELETE /dm/buckets/ call failed\n' + err.statusText);
  });
}
```

/public/index.html

Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка в этом коде?

Comment: У вас точно нормально вложен роутер? Покажите, как вы подключаете `/routes/oss.js`.

Comment: Да, точно, в противном случаи, я думаю, я бы не получал сообщение об ошибке 400. Кстати, все файлы по ссылке.